# Cling: getBaseURL returns null on some devices and works on others

Tags: java, android, upnp

I'm working on an app that will scan devices on a network using the Cling application. I have tried to modify it so that I am able to see the IP address of the devices too using the getBaseURL method. However when I scan devices, some of them show up with an IP and the others return null. Is there any way to sort this out?

```
        @Override
    public String toString() {

        String name =
                device.getDetails() != null && device.getDetails().getFriendlyName() != null
                        ? device.getDetails().getFriendlyName() +device.getDetails().getBaseURL()
                        : device.getDisplayString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly enough, `org.teleal.cling.model.meta.DeviceDetails` has many constructors, but only two types: ones which get `friendlyName` but no `baseURL` (hence it is left null) and other (only two) which get both. `baseURL` is final private, so no chance you could set it afterwards. I personally don't understand the design decision (why a knowledge of `friendlyName` is considered superseding the knowledge of `baseURL`) but IMO there lies the problem. Put a breakpoint in the last constructor of `DeviceDetails` (the only one which sets the private members) and observe, from where it is being called (and through which specific constructor overload). Every UPnP device has a baseURL, it tells it in LOCATION header of its NOTIFY message. So the fact that `DeviceDetails` doesn't provide it is an issue of Cling not being interested in it (i.e. not calling the constructor which takes it).